# adb on Mac cannot detect Moto G device

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, adb

I just purchased a Verizon Moto G (Android 4.3) to use for on-device Android testing.  However, when I connect it to my 2011 MacBook Pro (running Lion), it does not show up in `adb`.  I tried both running `adb devices` and using DDMS in Eclipse, neither of which showed any device.

I enabled USB debugging and I know that my cable works because when I set the USB computer connection to 'Camera', iPhoto launches and connects to the phone just fine.  I also downloaded Android File Transfer, which also seems to connect.

I don't really know what other information would be helpful, and I've spent a lot of time looking for a solution to no avail.  Let me know if I can add any information that would be useful.

Comment: make sure to use the latest `adb` version - http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r19.0.1-macosx.zip

Comment: yeah I made sure that everything was up to date, but it still didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I didn't have EasyTether installed on this device, the drivers were still installed on my computer which was causing problems.

This solved it:
http://intohand.com/blog/post/android-debug-bridge-not-just-working-on-mac

Comment: Linked page is gone... :(

Comment: Updated to fix the broken link

Comment: @stealthcopter Broken again.

Comment: please fix the broken link :(

Comment: Linked is gone, update the link please

Answer (score 3):

Check here, specially 5.2

http://esausilva.com/2010/10/02/how-to-set-up-adb-android-debug-bridge-in-mac-osx/

*Also make sure you have your phone plugged in and have USB Debugging turned on (Settings > Applications > Development)
In Android 4.2.x and up Developer Options is hidden, to make it visible, do the following
Tap seven times in Build Number: Settings > About Phone > Build Number
You will get a message saying you have enabled Developer Options or something like that, go back to Settings and you will see Developer Options in there.*